# Scalafmt package name checker

Tags: scala, code-formatting, rules, package-name, scalariform

I have found a nice rule in scalariform that checks the package names and is as follows:

```
<check enabled="true" class="org.scalastyle.scalariform.PackageNamesChecker" level="warning">
 <parameters>
  <parameter name="regex">^[a-z][A-Za-z]*$</parameter>
 </parameters>
</check>
```

However, I couldn't find the corresponding rule for scalafmt in the docs. Is there something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, [Scalafmt](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/) is just a code formatter, meaning it won't flag stylistic errors but rather reformat your code according to the predefined rules you have set (for example, add a new line after a bracket, align case statements, etc). Its goal is only formatting code so that it looks consistent between developers.

On the other hand, [Scalastyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/) (with Scalariform) is defined as :

> Scalastyle examines your Scala code and indicates potential problems with it.

So it defines ["check" rules](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-1.0.0.html), like the one you show in your question, to warn you about the fact that your code does not respect these rules. But it won't rewrite/reformat your code accordingly to these rules. It's more like a linting tool than a code formatter. Moreover, its scope is wider, as it provides more rules than just formatting : for example, it can check if you are using `null` with [`NullChecker`](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-1.0.0.html#org_scalastyle_scalariform_NullChecker).

Note that you can use both (and it's generally a good practice), as long as you are not defining contradictory rules!